# What is Glassfish "osgi-cache"?

Tags: glassfish

I am running GF 3 through Netbeans in a dev environment.  I notice that my domain contains a huge directory with over 300 subdirectories.  The parent directory is osgi-cache.

Does anyone know what this is?  I deleted the entries underneath, but as soon as I restarted my server, it came back.

They're not bothering me, but I am wondering why they need so much space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GlassFish modularity layers on top of OSGi, and the OSGi runtime that ships with GlassFish is Apache Felix. The OSGi specification states that the OSGi runtime must cache bundles and store bundle runtime state. You can learn more [here](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-bundle-cache.html) about the Apache Felix OSGi Cache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Link died - here's an updated one: [Apache Felix Framework Bundle Cache](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-bundle-cache.html)